# After applying skin and subdivision modifier, vertices are not visible on my object

Tags: modeling, modifiers, vertices

This is the tutorial I am following https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tzt55UfljGA
I am 2 minutes in.

Blender version: 3.1.0

After first applying a single vert, as done in the tutorial, I added in the skin and subdivision modifiers. However, the vertices are no longer visible in mine as they are in the tutorial.

Solutions I have attempted so far, but have not worked:

- make sure overlays are selected
- select 'wireframe' in viewport overlays
- go into edit mode instead of object mode

Below is a screenshot of my screen for reference.

[image]

UPDATE: The screenshot below is using x ray, also tried in edit mode.

[image]

Let me know what you all think,

Thankyou!

Comment: the vertex is at the same position as your origin, so select all in Edit mode and move your vertex with G if you want to see it, or maybe you've hidden it, in that case press Alt H

Comment: @moonboots That's not what the question is about, see my comment below the answer.

Comment: It's probably a feature of a previous version, I don't see how you can display the vertices, do you?

Comment: @moonboots i think it may be a previous version, i've sent the owner of the video a question hoping for a response!

Answer (score 0):

The solution proposed by [moonboots](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/34531/moonboots) in the comments worked for me. You have to select everything and move it upwards, so that the origin is not blocking the view onto the vertex. Then you can extrude it upwards with <kbd>E</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>.